# why splice not work properly in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make one demo in which i have one **checkbox** list .I am able to display the list using ng-repeat .

What I need if user click on one check box(only one checkbox is checked) .it display only one columns (100%) width .Which user checked two column it display two columns of equal width (50%).if user check three column it show three column of equal width ..As as if user checked four checkbox it show four column of equal width ..Initially some of checkbox is checked ( **checked:true**) ..

- my first step is to unchecked the **checked option** "training 3" ..but after unchecked it still display why ? I already use splice. method ?

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adBroe?editors=101

```
   init();
  function init(){
      for(var i =0;i<self.data.length;i++){
      var obj=self.data[i];
         if(obj.checked)
      {
        self.selectedList.push(obj);
      }
    }
    alert('starting '+self.selectedList.length)
  }

  self.checkBoxClick=function(obj,i){
    if(obj.checked)
      {
        alert('if')
        self.selectedList.push(obj);
      }else
        {
          alert('else'+i);
          self.selectedList.splice(i,1);
        }
    alert(self.selectedList.length);

   }

})
```

here is i am trying to display

```
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div ng-repeat="i in vm.selectedList" class='col-xs-{{12/vm.selectedList.length}}'>
        {{i.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: qctually Question is similar but there is some problem in that splice not work if I checked initially some checkbox

Comment: will I remove this post ..But I saw guideline that only ask one Question on each Question

Comment: It's ok to ask another question about your code if you continue to have issues.  However, if you are going to do so, it's best to try to make sure that the new question doesn't appear to be a copy of the first question.  And for the record, `.splice()` works perfectly fine, it's a well tested piece of code.

Comment: check my alerts ..in starting array length is two which is fine ...But when I unchecked the third option ...then again the count is two..it showed be 1 ..

Comment: Your array has only 2 items and you're trying to do `splice(3, 1)`. It's not working because your logic is wrong, not because of `splice`

Comment: Give it a try: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxWgVb?editors=101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be much simpler. In HTML you don't even need `ngChange` handler, just bind to checked property:

```
  <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat='v in vm.data'>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model='v.checked'> {{v.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
```

and then render columns with just `ngRepeat`:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in filteredList = (vm.data | filter:{checked:true})" class='col-xs-{{12/filteredList.length}}'>
    {{i.name}}
  </div>
```

So as the result, clean controller without any logic at all, with Angular doing all necessary column filtering using template `vm.data | filter:{checked:true}`.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEBydL?editors=101

Comment: could you please explain this ng-repeat="i in filteredList = (vm.data | filter:{checked:true})"

Comment: vm.data is assign to filteredList  list (same reference) ? and how filter works ..it check all in vm.data.in other words {checked:true} chaeck in all object in vm.data

Comment: With the expression `filteredList = (vm.data | filter:{checked:true})"` you create a new "variable" `filteredList` so you can reuse it in `{{12/filteredList.length}}` without need to write `{{12/(vm.data | filter:{checked:true}).length}}` which is less efficient and harder to read.

Comment: `filter` is similar to normal JS filter method, in this case it fillters out array elements with `checked:false`.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are trying to remove it from 2nd index while training 3 is present at 0th index.

```
else
    {
      alert('unchecked '+i);
      var index = self.selectedList.indexOf(obj);
      self.selectedList.splice(index,1);

    }
```

change your else part to this. and it will work fine.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVWeQ?editors=101